# return the first element with a difference from two lists of lists and stop to compare

Tags: python, list, compare, sublist, delta-index

I work on a project on python and I need to return the first delta (difference) beetween two lists of lists. And each position in the inside list refer to a name.

I succed to return the first delta for each parameter but I would like to stop at the first sublist with a delta.

My actual code is :

```
l_name = ["TIME", "ALPHA", "BETA"]         # the list of names
liste1 = [[1, 2, 3.0], [2,5.045,6.003], [3, 8.03, 9], [4, 10.5, 5.5]]     # values of all name in one sublist by step time
liste2 = [[1, 2, 3.0], [2,5.045,6.005], [3, 8.0029, 9], [4, 10.5, 5.5555]]
abs_tol = 0.00001                # tolerence to found a delta

def search_var_delta():
    for i in range(len(l_name)):
        for k in range(len(liste1)):
            a = liste1[k][i]
            b = liste2[k][i]
            diff = abs(a-b)
            if diff >= abs_tol :
                print("the delta : {}".format(diff),
                      "the index : {}".format(k+1),
                      "the parameter : {}".format(l_par[i]))
                break

search_var_delta()
```

I use break to stop to compare the sublist but it continu to compare the next sublist.

Output :

```
('the delta : 0.0271', 'the index : 3', 'the parameter : ALPHA')
('the delta : 0.002', 'the index : 2', 'the parameter : BETA')
```

But I would like only:

```
('the delta : 0.002', 'the index : 2', 'the parameter : BETA')
```

because it's the first index with a delta

if I add  `return l_par[i]` it will print the ALPHA one but as we seen it's in index 3 so not in the first sublist with the delta.

Comment: `l_par` is not defined.

Comment: You're only breaking out of the inner loop, the outer one will continue running. You could change the for loop to a while loop and add a condition or create a boolean variable which you set in the inner loop before you break and use it to break the outer loop as well.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is done with a flag around inner loop but in Python you could use [for ... else](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

```py
def search_var_delta():
    for i in range(len(l_name)):
        for k in range(len(liste1)):
            # ...
            if diff >= abs_tol :
                # ...
                break
        else:
            continue
        break
```

The trick is the code inside `else` statement executes when the inner `for` loop terminates but not when it is terminated by `break` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
l_name = ["TIME", "ALPHA", "BETA"]
liste1 = [[1, 2, 3.0], [2,5.045,6.003], [3, 8.03, 9], [4, 10.5, 5.5]]
liste2 = [[1, 2, 3.0], [2,5.045,6.005], [3, 8.0029, 9], [4, 10.5, 5.5555]]
tolerance = 0.00001
def process():
    for i, v in enumerate(zip(liste1, liste2), 1):
        for j in range(len(v[0])):
            if (delta := abs(v[0][j]-v[1][j])) > tolerance:
                print(f'Delta = {delta:.3f}, index = {i}, parameter = {l_name[j]}')
                return
process()
```

[Note: You'll need Python 3.8+]

Answer (score 0):

Note : sorry for the mistake l_par is l_name. I forgot to change the name.

Ok the answer was simple sorry,

It only need to reverse the for loop and use return :

```
def search_var_delta():
    for k in range(len(liste1)):
        for i in range(len(l_name)):
            a = liste1[k][i]
            b = liste2[k][i]
            diff = abs(a-b)
            if diff >= abs_tol :
                print("the delta : {}".format(diff),
                      "the index : {}".format(liste1[k][0]),
                      "the parameter : {}".format(l_name[i]))
                return [diff, liste1[k][0], l_name[i]]

search_var_delta()
```